# Why does my button's style change when I click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

[image]

I edited my buttons' style, but when I click on one, a function is called and changes the value (via ajax, if that affects anything), but the button changes as on the image. This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':button').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#ID').val(this.id);
    var tmp = this.id;
    $.ajax({
      type: $('#klik').attr("method"),
      url: $('#klik').attr("action"),
      data: $('#klik').serialize(),
      success: function(d) {
        alert(d)
        $('#' + tmp).val(d);
        const button = document.getElementById(tmp);
        button.disabled = true;
        if (d == 'bomba') {
          alert('bb');
        }

      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Greska')
      }
    });
  });
});
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr")
  for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    var elem = document.createElement('input');
    elem.className = 'gumb';
    elem.type = 'button';
    elem.id = 'r' + i + 's' + j;
    elem.value = '';
    elem.innerHTML = elem.value;
    docFrag.appendChild(elem);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(docFrag);
  document.body.appendChild(row);
}
```

This is my CSS:

```
.gumb {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your buttons are aligning to a baseline (the bottom of the `2` lines up with the bottom of empty buttons). Make sure to check your button styles regarding your text, especially `vertical-align`.

Comment: the included code sample doesn't include any css! from the picture, it looks like your css is causing the problem.

Comment: Your problem is purely CSS related but you are only providing javascript... Could you provide html and css instead? It would make things way easier. But if I have to guess, it has to do with buttons being empty... Try using a &nbsp; as value for empty buttons?

Comment: This is my css, just with different colour. `.gumb {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to align the text. Something like this:

`.gumb {
  vertical-align: middle;
}`